# DotNetOpenAuth and FIPS Server Error

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am currently using **DotNetOpenAuth v4.1.0.12182** to perform simple *Relying Party* functionality and was able to get it working (tested Google and Yahoo) without even adding any web.config entries.  However, this site will be deployed onto web servers which have the following setting enabled:

1. Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy
2. Find the setting "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms..." and set it to Enabled

Without this enabled the site works fine.  With this enabled I get the Server Error "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms".  I did find information on the dotnetopenauth v4-0 beta release page which mentions that, as of the DotNetOpenAuth 4.0 release, one of the changes was "FIPS-compliant SHA algorithms can now be configured in your .config files."

***What I need help with...***

I am seeking to know what config changes I need to make in order to get this FIPS message/error to go away.  I've looked at [http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/configuration-options/][2] but cannot find any clarity on it as to what is FIPS related.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

***Updated (7/10/2012)***

I'm providing the steps I've re-taken so the error can be replicated:

1. I used a fairly fresh install of Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (already had VS 2010 installed and perhaps some updates)
2. Added the Web Server Role
3. Added the .NET Framework 3.5.1 Feature
4. Enabled the Local Security Policy: System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing
5. Restarted the server
6. Compiled/built the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms sample and published it for use as a local IIS website
7. Ran into a URI error that caused me to have to set the App Pool to use ASP.NET v4.0
8. Ran into another error that caused me to have to "force install of .NET 4": http://devonenote.com/2010/06/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule/
9. Now the "Relying Party" webpage finally rendered so I clicked the Members Only link and then clicked the Sign In with a Yahoo ID option
10. After about a 2-3 second pause for it processing I receive:

> [**InvalidOperationException**: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.**SHA512**Managed..ctor() +4479214
>
> [**TargetInvocationException**: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.] when trying to do System.Security.Cryptography.**SHA512**.Create +11 and then System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName +1195
>
> [**TypeInitializationException**: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation' threw an exception.]  DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation.TryFindBestAssociation (cs:134)

*Troubleshooting steps...*

1. Added the config entries (based upon the link that Andrew provided) to the Framework64/v4.0.30319/Config/machine.config under the  tag. However, since I have not yet added the Security.Cryptogrophy DLL anywhere I removed those lines from the config (the ones dealing with HMACSHA512).
2. Restarted the machine
3. Browsed back to and clicked the Sign In with a Yahoo ID button

> [**InvalidOperationException**: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.**SHA384**Managed..ctor() +4486510
>
> [**TargetInvocationException**: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.] when trying to do System.Security.Cryptography.**SHA384**.Create +11 and then System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName +1195
>
> [**TypeInitializationException**: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation' threw an exception.] DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation.TryFindBestAssociation (cs:134)

What I noticed is that now it is complaining about SHA384 instead of SHA512, so the machine.config entry for SHA512 (telling ASP.NET to use the SHA512Cng class within System.Core) must be working!

So next I proceeded to add SHA384 & SHA256 entries, did an iisreset, and browsed back to and clicked the Sign In with a Yahoo ID button.  This time I was finally redirected to Yahoo, logged in, and was sent back to my localhost URL but received this FIPS error:

> [**InvalidOperationException**: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.]
>        System.Security.Cryptography.**HMACSHA256**..ctor(Byte[] key) +4491026

So now I proceeded with the following:

1. Added in the HMACSHA512 machine.config line I originally took out and duplicated it for HMACSHA256
2. Added the Security.Cryptography.dll file from the codeplex project referenced in Andrew's response to the GAC (windows\assembly) as per this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/12/02/cryptoconfig.aspx)
3. Restarted the machine
4. Browsed to and clicked the Yahoo button again but received the same error

It appears as if the new Cryptography DLL was not being "picked up" by ASP.NET and used.  So, next I tried:

1. Removing the DLL from the GAC
2. Restarting the machine
3. Added the Cryptography DLL as a reference to the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms sample and re-compiled and published it, overriding the exisiting IIS website files
4. Browsed to and clicked the Yahoo button again but received the same error

#### Any ideas on how I can get past this problem with **HMACSHA256**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Andrew's comment/link I was able to get the solution working.  However, I was never able to overcome the FIPS issue using .NET Framework 3.5.  I had to upgrade to .NET Framework 4.0 and then add the following to the root configuration element of the **machine.config** XML file:

```
<mscorlib>
   <cryptographySettings>
      <cryptoNameMapping>
         <cryptoClasses>
            <cryptoClass CoreSHA512="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <cryptoClass CoreSHA384="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <cryptoClass CoreSHA256="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
         </cryptoClasses>
         <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512" class="CoreSHA512"/>
         <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384" class="CoreSHA384"/>
         <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256" class="CoreSHA256"/>
      </cryptoNameMapping>
   </cryptographySettings>
</mscorlib>
```

In case the XML was stripped out above, follow the link that Andrew provided and you'll find the XML in the post by **joeudwin**.  I removed the lines for "TestHMACSHA512" and duplicated the lines for "TestSHA512" for 384 and 256 entries.  I did **not** need to download Security.Cryptography.dll from CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure .NET itself to create the FIPS-compliant versions of the required algorithms.  Please check out this [previously filed and fixed issue](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/47), including the comments, for guidance on how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I've read the referenced material and done the following: (1) Added the Security.Cryptography.dll from the clrsecurity CodePlex project to my web app VS project (2) Added <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false" /> to the Devenv.exe.config to prevent VS from throwing errors when compiling, (3) Added the <mscorlib><cryptographySettings> blocks to the Machine.config for both my /Framework/V2.0.50727 and /Framework/v4.0.30319 versions (my app targets .NET 3.5) (4) Published the site to my dev IIS and still get the Parset Error regarding FIPS

Comment: I've also restarted my machine to ensure the changes/settings have taken effect but I still get a "Server Error in '/' Application" - Parser Error Message: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cyptographic algorithms. And it is saying the source is line 1 on my default.aspx page (which doesn't have any DotNetOpenAuth classes used on it), which is the Page declaration line.

Comment: I since also added the <mscorlib> blocks to the Framework64 folder for both .NET v2 and v4 and deployed the Security.Cryptography.dll to the GAC instead of as a [bin] reference within my website project.  Now I only get a FIPS error on my login.aspx page (which does invoke DotNetOpenAuth class) with the following culprit: [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation' threw an exception.] DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation.TryFindBestAssociation (line 162)  Hopefully this helps as I'm at a loss.

Comment: Per https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/47, the "HMACSHA algorithms still need to be converted".  This has since been completed and along with the machine.config entry (mentioned in my post/answer) I now have it working.